# Как организовать выполнение команд в фоне при CQRS подходе?

Tags: архитектура, cqrs

Вопрос больше архитектурный.

Начал использовать CQRS подход в web-приложении и столкнулся с одним вопросом.

Часть команд нужно выполнять в раилтайме, а часть в фоне.

Понятно что команды которые нужно выполнить в фоне кладутся в очередь и обработчик, в фоне, разбирает очередь и кидает команды на шину (CommandBus) для выполнения. Тут вопросов нет.

Вопрос возникает в том как класть команду в очередь на обработку.

Я вижу две реализации:

**Вариант 1**

Самый простой вариант и возможно самый правильный. В контроллере класть команду сразу в очередь, а не отправлять на шину.

По идее, именно контроллер определяет нужно ли выполнять команду прямо сейчас или выполнить ее в фоне, а сейчас быстро отдать пользователю контент.

**Вариант 2**

Отправлять команды на шину, а к шине подключить Middleware который будет проверять нужно ли команду выполнить сейчас или потом. Если потом, то помечать команду как отложенную и кидать ее в очередь. А в обработчике очереди, при повторном попадании команды на шину, проверять была ли команда отложена и если да, то выполнять ее.

В этом случае команда, а не контроллер, определяет нужно ли ее выполнять в фоне. Контроллер уже не знает ни о какой очередь, он просто отправляет команду на шину, как обычно. Однако, в этом случае команда всегда будет выполнятся в фоне даже если мы решим выполнить ее в консоли, в риалтайме.

Какой вариант вам кажется правильней? Если у вас есть другие идеи по реализации, опишите их пожалуйста в ответе к этому вопросу.